# Why is it bad to do non sequential writes to a write-combined memory range?

Tags: winapi, memory, memory-management

I have read that it's important to not leave "holes" when you are writing to a memory range that is marked as write-combined, but I don't know why that's the case. Can someone explain why?

Comment: I guess it will force the CPU to write the cache line early. Maybe it can only combine sequential writes.